# overriding and calling a parent method from subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I am sub-classing PrintWriter to add additional functionality: (full source added per request).

```
public class MyPrintWriter extends PrintWriter{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyPrintWriter mpw = new MyPrintWriter();
        mpw.print("Test...");
    }

    public MyPrintWriter(){
        super(System.out);
    }
    private void doAdditionalFunctionality(){
        super.write("**AdditionalFunctionality**");
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String s, int off, int len) {
        doAdditionalFunctionality();
        super.write(s, off, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        doAdditionalFunctionality();
        super.print(s);
    }
}
```

however, when I run it, I get: `java.lang.StackOverflowError` (pun also intended)

How do I best apply the 'decorator' pattern in this case?

**Stack Trace** (as requested)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.String.length(String.java:623)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
at util.MyPrintWriter.doAdditionalFunctionality(MyPrintWriter.java:24)
at util.MyPrintWriter.write(MyPrintWriter.java:29)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
at util.MyPrintWriter.doAdditionalFunctionality(MyPrintWriter.java:24)
at util.MyPrintWriter.write(MyPrintWriter.java:29)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
at util.MyPrintWriter.doAdditionalFunctionality(MyPrintWriter.java:24)
...
```

Comment: can you post the stack, I want to see where does it repeat

Comment: The code as written looks OK. I think you need to add the test code and the stack trace.

Comment: what is the type of the value you are passing to write() in doAdditionalFunctionality()?

Comment: also, do you overload any other methods?

Comment: I think it is something to do with the fact that `PrintWriter.write(String s)` calls `write(s, 0, s.length())` - if I take out the override for that method, it works!

Comment: You wouldn't have all these problems if, instead of extending PrintWriter, you wrapped (or decorated) it.

Comment: @xirt Yes - `write(String)` is a convenience method; you can achieve the desired functionality by only overloading the `write(String, int, int)` version.

Comment: @JB Nizet I wanted it to be cast-able to PrintWriter as I use that elsewhere, and there's no PrintWriter interface...

Comment: @Alex - that is the best solution so far.  If you put that in an answer, I'll tick it. - no actually, that doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  private void doAdditionalFunctionality(){
        super.write("**AdditionalFunctionality**");
    }
```

to

```
  private void doAdditionalFunctionality(){
        super.write("**AdditionalFunctionality**", 0, "**AdditionalFunctionality**".length());
    }
```

Your problem is that super.write(String) is calling write(String, int, int), which you have overridden.

Comment: I think it would be simpler to remove the overridden version of `write(String)` and let it call through to the overridden `write(String, int, int)`.

Comment: but he didn't override write (and he doesn't need to)

Comment: Yes - though I prefer the:
    `String af = "**AdditionalFunctionality**";`
    `super.write(s,0,af.length())`
but that is just cosmetic... :-)

Comment: @MK My mistake - the code in the original question had `write` overridden; OP has since edited it to have substantially different meaning.